# What does document.vulnerable do?

Tags: javascript, xss

Im getting more into preventing xss attacks and one of the ways I'm doing that is by finding and fixing exploits.  I noticed that i see document.vulnerable in alot of the attacks I've logged.

I can't seem to find much documentation on this so I'm left wondering what does it do or what is it for?

Comment: They're probably just setting a flag, `document.vulnerable` isn't a native JS property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK it's just a way of testing if an attack works. You try to inject a script containing `document.vulnerable = true` into a page, then you go to the page and see if document.vulnerable is set.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense.  Escpecially if you were using an automated script to to try and infect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can find it is just a flag set by the XSS vulnerability tests. I am basing this on all the tests I have seen and

> ...the resulting HTML page sets a specific JavaScript value (document.vulnerable=true) then the tool marks the page as vulnerable to the given XSS...

seen in the documentation for this FF add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xss-me/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it does anything, it just sets a property on the document object called `vulnerable`.

When you see HTML code like: `<IMG SRC="javascript:document.vulnerable=true;">` when looking at XSS attacks, it's just a way of saying "allowing JavaScript code to be inserted here is dangerous".